# How to prove transitivity on proper subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm new to set theory, and recently I came across with a problem:

> Prove transitivity on proper subsets, that is if $A \subset B$ and $B \subset C$, then $A \subset C$.

From what I've learned so far, proper subset, $A \subset B$ iff $(\forall x)(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B) \land A \neq B$. In other words, if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \neq B$, then $A \subset B$.

From what's given, $(\forall x)(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B)$ and $(\forall x)(x \in B \Rightarrow x \in C)$, I can prove $(\forall x)(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in C)$ with specialization, transitivity, and generalization. Thus $A \subseteq C$ is the conclusion. Only if I can prove $A \neq C$ from $A \neq B$ and $B \neq C$, together with $A \subseteq C$, I can prove $A \subset C$.

$A = B$ iff $(\forall x)(x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B)$ (axiom of extent), thus $A \neq B$ iff $\neg (\forall x)(x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B)$, iff $(\exists x)(\neg (x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B))$, iff $$(\exists x)((x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \notin A \land x \in B)).$$

So this is where I got stuck, that is, given
$$(\exists x)((x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \notin A \land x \in B))$$ and
$$(\exists x)((x \in B \land x \notin C) \lor (x \notin B \land x \in C)),$$ how to prove that
$$(\exists x)((x \in A \land x \notin C) \lor (x \notin A \land x \in C))?$$

Sorry if this is a really stupid question and thank in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Hint: if $B \subset C$, there is an element $c \in C$ that is not in $B$ and then if $A \subseteq B$, $c$ can't be in $A$ either.

Comment: It might help to understand a proof by considering examples: Let a,b,c be distinct sets , Consider A =  {a}, B = {a,b}, C = {a,b,c} so we have at A $\subset$ B $\subset$ C, can you see why A $\subset$ C ?

Comment: $A\ne B$ means either there is an $x \in A; x\not \in B$ or $x\in B; x\not \in A$. If $A\subset B$ the former is impossible so it have to be the latter. So to prove $A\subseteq C$ but $A\ne C$ you just need to show, for all $x\in A$ then $x \in C$ (which you did) and that there is a $y \in C$ where $y \not \in B$  (Because $B\subsetneq C$) and since $y\not \in B$ we can't have $y \in B$ (Because $A\subset B$)  so $y \not \in A$.  SO $A \ne C$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When proving that $A\neq C$, you can't use just $A\neq B$ and $B\neq C$. Because from these two facts only, it is entirely possible that $A=C$. You have to include what you know about the set inclusions.

Because of $B\neq C$ and $B\subseteq C$ together, there must be some $c\in C$ such that $c\notin B$.

More specifically, look at your
$$
(\exists x)((x \in B \land x \notin C) \lor (x \notin B \land x \in C)).
$$
Let $c$ be one of the elements that the above sentence tells us exists. The inclusion $B\subseteq C$ means one of the terms in the disjunction, namely $c\in B\land c\notin C$, is false, so you may safely remove that without changing the truth of the statement. Thus we are left with $c\notin B\land c\in C$.

Since $A\subseteq B$ and $c\notin B$, we must also have $c\notin A$. This lets us conclude $A\neq C$.

(Note that we never used $A\neq B$ here, and indeed, $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subset C$ together do imply $A\subset C$, which is a marginally stronger result than what you were asked for. Similarly, we could have used $A\neq B$ instead to get a hold of our $c\notin A$, this time with $c\in B$, which would have yielded that $A\subset B$ and $B\subseteq C$ imply $A\subset C$.)